# Match values in two columns having same number digits in data fame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with two columns named as ID_1 and ID_2. I want to match number in ID_1 with number in ID_2 in which they have same number digits.

```
ID_1    ID_2

203221652   203252612

338871000   338000781

365676566   366527042

366516390   NaN

366717450   NaN

366725230   NaN

366725240   NaN

366727190   NaN
```

I would like the output like this:

```
ID_1    ID_2

203221652   203252612

338871000   338000781

365676566   NaN

366516390   NaN

366717450   NaN

366725230   NaN

366725240   366527042

366727190   NaN
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the columns numeric or text?

Comment: they are numeric

Comment: Would you consider `322222222` and `333322222` to have the same number digits?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, the columns are numeric

Comment: @Derek O, no. Because the times appearance of a digit is different.

Comment: If you want to match two sequences composed of the same items but permuted into different orderings, you want to identify a normalised, canonical representation so that scrambled variations all map onto the same normalised sequence.  In your case, you might make a new column that has ID_1 values with the digits in ascending order, and similarly for ID_2.

Comment: @TMBailey, thank you. I will consider about it.